# Можно задать таблице скролл?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Скажите пожалуйста можно таблице задать скролл и если да то как ?
2. Как можно сделать чтобы при клике иконки справа (серые)  меняли цвет ?
3. Как можно сделать чтобы при клике **показать все** таблица дальше раскрывалась ?

Comment: 1. Создать обертку и ей задать соотв. требования. 2. Использовать svg или иконочный шрифт 3. Для этого использовать необходимо javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создаем обертку `.table-container` со следующими стилями

`.table-container{
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}`

2. Для примера использован иконочный шрифт [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=free) (Для первого ряда добавлены иконки)
3. При клике на кнопку добавляем новый класс контейнеру таблицы

Пример

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
let tableContainer = document.querySelector('.table-container');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  tableContainer.classList.add('show');
  this.classList.add('hide');
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block{
  padding: 20px;
}

.table-container{
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.table-container.show{
  max-height: 100%;
}

table{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;  
}
td{
  padding: 5px;
}
tr:nth-of-type(even){
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.btn{
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
.btn.hide{
  display: none;
}

[class*=fa-]:hover{
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="block">
  <div class="table-container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></td>
        <td><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></td>
        <td><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
        <td>td</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  
  <button class="btn">Show all</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Здравствуйте  Вы можете помочь и улучшить код ?